# display /var/log/messages in html/php output?

Tags: linux, bash, apache, logging

I am trying to display the output of /var/log/messages or similar (../secure for instance) in a webpage that I access through a webserver on the same host.

Should I use bash to tail -f >> the messages file to a new output file and display that text file in the html page, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!
idiglivemusic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>toyLogs</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div><p><?php include('/var/www/html/accesslog.txt'); ?></p></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a way to display actual file contents online without the need to reload the page, then you should setup a [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) server.

You can build a WebSocket server using a framework such as [phpDaemon](https://daemon.io/), [ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org/), [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/), [icicle](https://github.com/icicleio), or implement your own server with the help of PHP extensions wrapping asynchronous libraries: [event](https://pecl.php.net/package/event), [ev](https://pecl.php.net/package/ev), or similar.

I've chosen a random framework from the list above: Ratchet. Ratchet is based on ReactPHP. ReactPHP chooses a backend for the event loop from the following list:
- `libevent` extension,
- `libev` extension,
- `event` extension,
-  or an internal class based on the built-in `stream_select()` function.

As a maintainer of the `event` extension, I've chosen `event`.

I've written a "quick" example just to give you idea of how it might be implemented. You'll most likely have to work out your own version, maybe using different tools. But the code should give you an impulse.

**src/MyApp/Server.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Server implements MessageComponentInterface {
  protected $clients;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
  }

  public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $this->clients->attach($conn);
    echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
  }

  public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
    printf("Connection %d sending '%s' to %d other connection%s\n",
      $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
      if ($from !== $client) {
        $client->send($msg);
      }
    }
  }

  public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $this->clients->detach($conn);
    echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
  }

  public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
    $conn->close();
  }

  public function broadcast($msg) {
    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
      $client->send($msg);
    }
  }
}
```

**server.php**

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Server;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
  new HttpServer(
    new WsServer(
      $my_app_server = new Server()
    )
  ),
  9989
);

$loop = $server->loop;
$filename = '/var/log/messages';

$loop->addPeriodicTimer(5, function ()
  use ($filename, $my_app_server)
  {
    static $stat_info;

    if ($stat_info == null) {
      clearstatcache(true, $filename);
      $stat_info = stat($filename);
    }

    clearstatcache(true, $filename);
    $st = stat($filename);

    $size_diff = $st['size'] - $stat_info['size'];
    echo "Diff = $size_diff bytes\n";

    if ($size_diff > 0) {
      $offset = $stat_info['size'];
      $bytes = $size_diff;
    } elseif ($size_diff < 0) {
      // The file is likely truncated by `logrotate` or similar utility
      $offset = 0;
      $bytes = $st['size'];
    } else {
      $bytes = 0;
    }

    $stat_info = $st;

    if ($bytes) {
      if (! $fp = fopen($filename, 'r')) {
        fprintf(STDERR, "Failed to open file $filename\n");
        return;
      }
      if ($offset > 0) {
        fseek($fp, $offset);
      }
      if ($msg = fread($fp, $bytes)) {
        $my_app_server->broadcast($msg);
      }
      fclose($fp);
    }
  }
);

$server->run();
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9989');
  conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
  };
  conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("Msg from server", e.data);
  };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'll skip the steps required to setup a basic test environment using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Assuming you have successfully configured the test environment for the files above, you'll be able to run the server with the following command:

```
php server.php
```

Check, if the user has permissions to read `/var/log/messages`. On my system only `root` can read the file. So you might need to run the above-mentioned command with `sudo`(root permissions).

Now you can open `test.html` in a browser and look at the console output. Then trigger some event which is normally logged to the messages file. For instance, you can invoke `sudo` with a wrong password. The server should detect the changes within interval of 5 seconds, then send it to the WebSocket clients.

Comment: This is looks like a complete solution for the problem :D

Comment: Ruslan, thanks for your response. Very thorough! Can you please clarify where the src/MyApp/Server.php file goes? Do you mean for it to go in /usr/src/MyApp/Server.php??? (!!!)

Comment: @iDigLiveMusic, it's just a [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) within your project directory which can by anywhere on the file system. See Ratchet's ["hello world" example](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world)

Comment: Great I appreciate all the help. While this involved more than what I looking for, I still upvoted as I am sure this will probably end up helping some unsuspecting reader :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using tail -f, that means that you'll be continuously getting data from the file while it grows as the command runs. 
You can use cat or tail -n. Also, of course, you can access files directly by creating a symbolic or hard link to them (ln source-file link-file, ln -s source-file link-file) - but make sure, that your web-server has enough rights to access them.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Sergey! I ended up with a solution that avoids symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your html-server has rights to access the page and read the page (with something like `cat`, `tail`, `grep`).
In `<html>` put the output between `<pre>` and `</pre>`.

Answer (score 0):

**Method  1**

In one of your base directories, create a symbolic link

```
ln -s /var/log/messages messages
```

If the directory belonged to say, `test.web`, access the log with
unmesh
    http://test.web/messages

**Method 2**

If you're looking for a `php` script then, first create the link as mentioned in method 1. Then, create a new file, say, `readlog.php` in the base directory of `test.web` with the below content :

```
<?php
readfile(“$DOCUMENT_ROOT/messages”);
?>
```

Access the `readlog.php` like :

```
http://test.web/readlog.php
```

**Requirement:**

`Read` access should be enabled for all users for `/var/log/messages`.

**Note:**

Setting `read` option for `/var/log/messages` for the whole world is **NOT** a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Because of the obvious security concerns (which you've pointed out) I might pass on this one, but it technically addresses my issue albeit using php instead of just html